# Logging errors in Shiny using logging library

Tags: r, logging, shiny

I'm trying to add logging to my app using `logging` library , but it seems hard to write *errors* to logs. Suppose we have this code:

```
observeEvent(input$btn, {
    write.csv(data, file = filename, row.names = FALSE)
})
```

How can we write something to log if error occurs?
I managed to do it like this:

```
observeEvent(input$btn, {
  tryCatch({
    write.csv(data, file = filename, row.names = FALSE)
    loginfo(paste0("Saved data to Server: ", input$DP_dataset_name))
  }, error=function(err) {
    logerror(paste0("Error when saving data - incorrect file name: ", input$file_name))
  })
})
```

Though it doesn't seem elegant at all.

Full example:

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(logging)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("dataset_name", "Dataset name", "testName"),
  actionButton("Save", "Save data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  basicConfig()
  observeEvent(input$Save, {
    tryCatch({
      write.csv(mtcars, file = paste0(getwd(), "/", input$dataset_name, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
      loginfo(paste0("Saved data: ", paste0(getwd(), "/", input$dataset_name, ".csv")))
    }, error = function(err) {
      logerror(paste0("Error when saving data - incorrect file name: ", input$dataset_name))
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any advices how can I get the needed result in a better way?